# Customize Android 4.0 (ICS) Bluetooth HID

Tags: bluetooth, customization

I have a Targus bluetooth presentation remote. It acts a mouse amoungt other things. I was hoping to find an app that allows me to capture the different buttons on the mouse and customize them. For instance one button just types "b" when pressed which has no use. I want an app that is able to capture the button and reassign it to something more useful.

Any Ideas?

Comment: My first thought was to a Wiimote app like [Wiimote Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ccpcreations.android.WiiUseAndroid&hl=en). These talk to the Wiimotes via bluetooth and map the controller buttons to keyboard inputs in the OS. I doubt these apps would work correctly with your Targus remote, but this kind of thing should be theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom keyboard layouts is an official feature of Android 4.1 Jelly Bean.

It's called "User-installable keymaps", see more [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html).

If you don't want to wait/upgrade:
Besides this, Android uses  keymaps also for bluetooth HID devices (your device, some number keypads, Apple bluetooth keyboard, etc.). More info how to change this is [here](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/keymaps_keyboard_input.html).